# Moving the Outlook reading pane to the left

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I've been searching on the internet for the past while, and I can't find a way to move the Outlook reading pane **left**.

The only options are Right, Bottom, or Off.

Is anybody aware of how the reading pane can be moved **left** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put the Reading Pane to the left of the list of messages.

Comment: Need a link to e.g. an authoritative KB article. Need to know which version(s) this fact applies to.

Comment: @Rich The question is tagged [microsoft-outlook-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook-2010) and in my experience software makers do not document things that the software does not do.

Comment: @WilliamJackson please note "Outlook 2020 does not have a werewolf detector or sasquatch migration tracker." :)